# Custom x-axis labels in d3 bar charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I am new to d3 and I am trying to organize my data based on some actions. I looked at other posts on here and followed similar answers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636526/set-custom-x-axis-labels-in-d3-bar-charts) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549761/specify-x-axis-labels-in-d3)), but for some reason, the x-axis is not displaying the order I created in `var workflow_actions = ["SB","SE","DR","RD","EN","RE"];` instead it is in a different order.

Perhaps the best method is to use ordinal scales instead? See [D3 API](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md)

I believe the issue is on this line: `x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.phase; }));`

This was the suggestion per Stack Overflow:

```
var workflow_actions = ["SB","SE","DR","RD","EN","RE"];
var formatAction = function(d) {
    return workflow_actions[d % 6];
}

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(workflow_actions);
```

Here is my code:

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([SB","SE","DR","RD","EN","RE"]) # just added based on API
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var workflow_actions = ["SB","SE","DR","RD","EN","RE"];
var formatAction = function(d) {
    return workflow_actions[d % 6];
}

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(workflow_actions);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var tipLabelMap = {
  #labels
};

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>" + getTipLabel(d.phase) + ":</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.count + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.json("mydata", function(error, data) {

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.phase; })); ## ISSUE!!!!
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Count");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.phase); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
});

function getTipLabel(phase) {
    return tipLabelMap[phase];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `workflow_actions` has some values which are different from the scale's domain, you don't want `tickValues` here, but `tickFormat` instead:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat((d,i) => workflow_actions[i]);
```

Here is a demo, with the scale's domain and the `workflow_actions` array:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["SU","SI","SE","CD","EN","RE"])
    .rangeRoundBands([20, 280], .1);

var workflow_actions = ["SB","SE","DR","RD","EN","RE"];

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat((d,i)=>workflow_actions[i]);
  
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,130)")
      .call(xAxis);
```

```css
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

EDIT: the above answer addresses the original question, where the `workflow_actions` was different from the domain. To know the OP's actual problem, read the comments below.

Comment: the domain is actually the same as the workflow actions. typo!! sorry about that. what changes when the domain and variable are the same??

Comment: Now I'm lost here: If the domain is the same, you don't need any change!

Comment: in that case, i probably don't even need the variable workflow_actions since the domain supplies the text. right?

Comment: Exactly. The ticks' order is simply the domain array order.

Comment: i fixed the typo above

Comment: can you correct the code above to show it without `var workflow_actions` now? thanks again!

Comment: The problem in your code is that you're setting the x scale domain again: `x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.phase; }));` Why are you doing that?

Comment: i got rid of it. it was from another coder. it kept overriding my x-axis. i think it may have been from a tutorial.

Comment: So, even getting rid of it, your x axis ticks are not in the same order as your domain's array?

Comment: now with the domain in the `var x = d3.scale.ordial()` they now are ! :) thank you!! i got rid of `workflow_actions`